# make child element fill 100% of parent with min-height set to 100%

Tags: html, css

I have an app that uses a sticky footer, however, I have a constraint that requires a content container to span 100% of its parent where this parent has a min-height: 100% defined. In this simplified example, inner is the content container and page-wrap is the parent. Min-height: 100% is required for sticky footer to behave correctly.

```
<div class="page-wrap">
  <div class=inner>
    <h1>.inner</h1>
    <button id="add">Add Content</button>  
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  <h1>.site-footer</h1>  
</footer>
```

Please see fiddle for example.

http://codepen.io/TroutZen/pen/OywGWg

Answer (score 0):

Could try using this:

```
.inner {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 142px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVpJLY)

Comment: This doesn't fully solve the issue at hand though, could add an `overflow: auto;` 

Is the footer supposed to be visible at all times?

Comment: constraints: 1) Footer must be visible at bottom when content < 100% 2) content background must stretch to meet the footer 2) Footer is pushed down when content expands beyond 100% viewport